# Problem rendering code blocks with Jekyll in .github.io site

Tags: jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

**The problem**

My post containing some code blocks renders them like "box in a box". 
This is the post: https://telatin.github.io/N50-with-conda/ and here what I see from Firefox: http://prntscr.com/oujb6u

**The code**

This is the source code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telatin/telatin.github.io/master/_posts/2019-08-19-N50-with-conda.md

I'm new in using Jekyll, and I tried both triple backticks (as I usually do in GitHub, and the four-spaces at the begin of the line (current implementation). Both renders the same.

**Question**

I don't understand if the problem is in the code I write or in the template I'm using. What should I do to have a nicer output (single framed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the generated HTML, you'll see that there are nested blocks with the same class `.highlight`:

```html
<div class="highlighter-rouge">
  <div class="highlight">
    <pre class="highlight">
      <code>CHECK=$(n50 contigs.fasta)</code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

What you can do is alter your CSS to be *more specific*:

i.e. instead of `.highlight`, use `div.highlight` for base code-block styles and use
`div.highlight > pre.highlight` to style the `pre` block elements if required.

Comment: Thanks, so it's not a problem in the markdown.
Since the I didn't write the template, do you think it's just a bug in the template (I'll look in that direction and for example check for updates ecc)?

Comment: Right. This issue is purely CSS.

Comment: The offending code is at: https://github.com/telatin/telatin.github.io/blob/23e33c3480c87147a49a24ba0610de0d59f51353/_sass/_highlights.scss#L2